# readme.md links on npm vs github

Tags: github, npm, markdown

**Bottom line:** Is there a way to create anchor links (table-of-content style) in a README.md file that will work in both NPM and GitHub ?

Hi all,

I have a README.md file that is both on GitHub and on NPM.
At the top of the file, there's a table-of-contents, which is just a list of links.
Each link should point to a header in the file.

After some googling and reading some stackoverflow answers, I tried the following:

`[Overview](#overview)` - But this resulted in NPM pointing all my links to my GitHub.

I resorted to just hard-coding the links so that they point to the proper anchors on NPM - but obviously this means that anyone clicking a link on GitHub would be redirected to the NPM page.

The README.md file can be found here: https://github.com/ujc/Layman.js/blob/master/README.md

Thx in adv!

Comment: I could be wrong, but I guess `[Overview](#overview)` is the best you can do.

Comment: figured as much...opened a ticket with NPM, maybe they'll know how to do it! (I'll update the question if I get an answer). Thx anyways!

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is to use plain HTML links. Both Github and NPM markdown presentations allow embedded HTML and it seems to work fine. E.g.

```
<a href="#my-heading">Link to My Heading</a>
```

...

```
# My Heading
```